# Breakpoint suddenly closes the "locals" window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug a variable in my code. I'm using a break point but when my mouse goes over any of the variables present in "locals" it the locals window suddenly closes down without any warning at all. Also a lot of the lines are empty. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Your window arrangement got to be quite a mess, hard to reason through possible causes of this mishap.  Perhaps it is time to use the Windows + Reset Window Layout command.

Comment: Could the code backing one of the properties shown be calling `Application.Exit`?  Could evaluating one of the properties have a stack overflow?  Could evaluating one of the properties be blocked due to a `lock` statement?  Could evaluating one of the properties be trying and failing to pump messages?  Since displaying objects in the watch window calls `ToString()` on all their reflected properties, really any code could be getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Your watch window contains an error message "Function evaluation was aborted."  That probably means one of the properties displayed has an infinite recursion, like so:

```
    readonly bool isSigned;
    public bool IsSigned { get { return IsSigned; } }
```

Fix the infinite recursion and the problem should go away:

```
    readonly bool isSigned;
    public bool IsSigned { get { return isSigned; } }
```

You can catch the `StackOverflowException` when it is thrown using Visual Studio by selecting from the menu bar "Debug" -> "Exceptions" -> "Find..." -> type "stackoverflow" -> check "Thrown" for `System.StackOverflowException` -> "OK"

[image]

If "Exceptions" does not appear in the "Debug" menu of your version of Visual Studio, follow the instructions for [To add the Exceptions command to the Debug menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#addexceptionscommand) for your VS version.

**update** Just checked, looks like Visual Studio won't break on the `StackOverflowException` if it's thrown in the watch window.  If you can't find the bug by code inspection, what you have to do to find the infinite recursion is to *delete everything in the watch window*, then add a line or lines in your actual code to access the properties that might be causing the recursion, `checkaoprimeiroradiobuttonG` in your case, e.g.

```
var tmp1 = checkaoprimeiroradiobuttonG;
var tmp2 = desactivabetaoadicionalG;
```

In that case the recursion should get caught.

Comment: @ng80092a - Instructions for doing this in VS2010 are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @ng80092a - Follow the instructions under "To add the Exceptions command to the Debug menu" on the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#addexceptionscommand